# Adding Elements to PFObject Array without Retrieving Object

Tags: javascript, arrays, parse-platform, parse-cloud-code

I have a `User` table and a `FriendRequest` join table.

`User`s create `FriendRequest` rows with `from`, `to` and `status` columns

When a user accepts a `FriendRequest`, he changes the status to `Accepted`, and a Cloud Code `afterSave` method is triggered, checking the status of the request.

If it is `Accepted`, both users should respectively be added to their friends array column.

Looks like this (apologies for not using UML):

[image]

The problem is that the accepting process as it is consumes **A LOT** of requests.

1- 1x request for: Change status to `Accepted`

2- 2x request for: Fetch both `User` objects to update friends column

3- 2x request for: saving both `User` with updated friend column

I would like to know if there is an ingenious way of reducing the number of requests, and more specifically, **is there a way to add elements to an array without retrieving its parent object?**

Answer (score 0):

I got to trim it down from 5 to 2 requests.

Instead of issuing a request to fetch both users, I simply identify which `User` I'm going to update by declaring it with its `id` locally.

Then, I update those 2 objects' `friends` columns with unique pointers to their soon-to-be-friends User.

Finally, I add both objects to be saved within an array, and call `saveAll` on that array.

```
Parse.Cloud.afterSave('FriendRequest', function(request) {

  var status = request.object.get("status");

  var sendingUser = request.object.get("from").id;
  var receivingUser = request.object.get("to").id;

  if (status == "Accepted") {
    var ReceivingUser = Parse.Object.extend("User");
    receivingUserObject = new ReceivingUser();
    receivingUserObject.id = receivingUser;

    var SendingUser = Parse.Object.extend("User");
    sendingUserObject = new SendingUser();
    sendingUserObject.id = sendingUser;

    receivingUserObject.addUnique("friends", sendingUserObject);
    sendingUserObject.addUnique("friends", receivingUserObject);

    var arrayToSave = [receivingUserObject, sendingUserObject];

    Parse.Object.saveAll(arrayToSave, {
      success: function(savedArray) {
        console.log("successfully saved friends");
      },
      error: function(error) {
        console.log("failure saving friends");
      }
    });
  }
});
```